# Evaluate issue: Is it the quote marks?

Tags: excel, vba, evaluate

In the immediate window, this works:

```
? range("FireResistantConsider").Column
```

This causes error 2015:

```
? Evaluate("range(""FireResistantConsider"").column")
```

So does this:

```
? Evaluate("range(" & chr(34) & "FireResistantConsider" & chr(34) & ").column")
```

Comment: Evaluate works with formulas, not code. It would be `Evaluate("COLUMN(FireResistantConsider)")`

Comment: Why are you trying to use `Evaluate` in the first place?

Comment: `Evaluate` is Excel's calculation engine doing the work, not VBA; there's no "evaluate" in VBA. Since `Range` is something that exists in the VBA object model, not in Excel, it can't be evaluated. Error 2015 is a NAME? error. If you can't type it in a cell and get a result, you can't `Evaluate` it.

Comment: Ah, thanks Rory, I get it.

Comment: BigBen it's complicated! The code has to be portable and adaptable. I don't want to hard code this into the vba for this reason. So I enter a function in a cell (formated ;;; to hide it). Then I evaluate the cell during runtime, returning a true or false to determine what to do at that point. 

This ultimately is working: 

strText = “index(FireResistantConsider, \, 1)=1”                           

‘ replace the \ character with the current for
strFormula = Replace(strText, "\", intCurrentRow)
If Evaluate(strFormula) Then ….